# How to return an array in a google spreadsheet column using custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a custom function in Google spreadsheet which filters the data from a column, having values in percentage. The idea is to check summation of values lying between range 1-5% is less than 15%. Once found populate all such percentage values in a single column, wherever i apply this formula.

I've written this code and when i debug it results in correct array values, however, it's not populating anything in the cells.

```
/**
 * Get the Filtered Data
 *
 * @return The range based on filters .
 * @customfunction
 */
function GetFilteredData() {
  try {
    var sum = 0;
    var actsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Utilization");
    var range = actsheet.getRange('M3:M').getValues();
    var Alast = range.filter(String).length;
    var filteredrange = [];
    for(var i=5;i>1;i--)
    {
      var cell = actsheet.getRange("P1");
      cell.setFormula("=SUM(FILTER(M3:M,M3:M<"+i+"%))")
      sum = actsheet.getRange('P1').getValue();
      if(sum <0.15)
      {
        filteredrange = findFilteredRange(range, i, Alast);
        break;
      }
    }
    return filteredrange;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
function findFilteredRange(datarange, criteria, lastcell){
  var fildata = [];
  for(var j = 0; j<lastcell; j++) {
    if(datarange[j] <= criteria/100) {
          fildata.push(datarange[j]*100);
    }
  }
  return fildata;
}
```

I am not sure why it is not showing any data in the cells. I expect it to return all such values, satisfying my condition in the cells where i apply the formula.

Comment: Check the types of your variables... What does it mean to multiply a JavaScript `Array` object by a JavaScript `double` object? You'll also want to make sure you flush the write buffer so that things you write in a script are computed before being read

Comment: Why not try to set the cell values from the script directly?

Comment: @tehhowch I'm new to this scripting, I'm multiplying them to get the result in terms of %. Can you please describe me what do you mean by second line?

Comment: @AMolina you mean by defining hard coded range, and then set values to each cell?

Comment: @Damien you can use the `setValues()` method ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)) to change the values over an entire range, you pass a 2D array to it that matches the range and the values are changed in the Sheet, it can be a more comfortable way of working with it.

Comment: @damien It is nonsense to multiply an `Array` by a value in JavaScript. It is probably the intent to multiply each *element* of that `Array` by that value, which involves iteration of the `Array`.

Comment: @tehhowch that's why i am multiplying inside for loop, each element with value 100.

Comment: Yes, but have you looked at the type of that element? Set a breakpoint in the debugger and actually take a good look at what kinds of objects your function and method calls are returning. Your code probably doesn't even reach that line, since you similarly compare an `Array` to a `number` using `<=`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fildata.push( [ datarange[j][0] * 100 ] ); // in square brackets
```

as the output needs to be a list-of-lists i.e. a 2-d array.

And just `datarange[j]` will give you the entire row.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still the same problem. I'd like to clarify i am trying to return the data using first method "GetFilteredData()". You meant to implement this change only in this particular line?

Comment: You'll need a share a sheet with sample data. The code isn't obvious. For instance, what is the `string` in `range.filter(String).length`?

Comment: I think the key is that the output needs to be a 2-d array. See the examples at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization

For example this function will return a 2-d array.

function getNumbers() {
  return [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ] ];
}

Comment: @ADW i'll send the sample file in sometime. the ```range.filter(String).length``` is being used to get the last row or the count in the single column. This i had taken from internet.